# Why is driver's test privatization in purvue of Israel's Supreme Court?

Tags: israel, judiciary, separation-of-powers

So this minor news article ("[High Court order against privatization of driving tests](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/Flash.aspx/364329)") caught my attention, by the fact that it seems like such a strange and insignificant topic to rise to Supreme Court level.

Why would something like decision to privatize drivers tests by a transportation ministry end up in Israel's Supreme Court?

Answer (score 3):

Earlier this year, that same source [reported](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/212787) on the unfolding situation.

A lower court previously filed an injunction against privatization, because the transportation agency had not followed the appropriate procedures to privatize the driver's license system. The judge who called for the injunction said:

> “The privatization process was apparently pursued without consultations or talks as required by law, therefore we order a temporary halt.”

The agency said they would appeal (and apparently they did, up to the Supreme Court), which explains how it ended up in the Supreme Court's hands.